# How to specify CLIENT when doing SQL SELECT statement against a Calculation View in Eclipse HANA View?

Tags: eclipse, hana, calculation

I have a Calculation View, which has set "Default Client" to "Session client". When viewing this Calculation View from ABAP program or Application layer, it is correctly showing entries and filtering based on logon Client. But when accessing it directly via SQL Editor in eclipse, it has no entries. I suspect it's because I have to specify the CLIENT. But I cannot find any documentation anywhere that shows how to specify this CLIENT in a SELECT statement in SQL Editor. My SQL Statement:

SELECT * FROM "_SYS_BIC"."ZPACKAGE/CV_MYCV"

[image]

Thanks!

Sample CV for demo purpose
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal reproducible Calculation View](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to be tested?

Comment: hi Sandra. I've updated the post with a sample CV. just a simple view exposing MARA table with MATNR and a calculated column with hardcoded 1. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the client at user level with `alter user set parameter client = '100'`.

As [documentation says](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.02/en-US/20d3459f75191014a7bbeb670bad8850.html#loio20d3459f75191014a7bbeb670bad8850__sql_alter_user_1sql_alter_user_user_parameter_option), users cannot set this parameter by themselves. Also if you check [`m_session_context`](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.02/en-US/20c50b73751910148ae9d5b996ff1e84.html) table you can see that this parameter is system scoped (field `section`), which means:

> USER=application defined variable using SET command or client API call, SYSTEM=predefined variable or server property

So there's no way to specify this parameter when accessing calculation view or after establishing the connection with `set` command.

You can verify your current client with:

```
select session_context('CLIENT')
from dummy
```

Also this parameter can be set in GUI in this section of user:
[image: USER ENTRY]

Comment: thanks! This solved the issue. I had thought there was a way to set this without any action from DB admin, but seems there's none unless I change the CV design itself

Comment: Client field is present for security, it separates the data and when you create a user in GUI, it is created in a single client. This concept was also applied to the HANA database and works internally (for some system tables like T006 or T000 it internally restricts the data even in plain select). So users should have no ability to change it by themselves.